# prevent ios7 pan gesture to pop view controller

Tags: ios7, pan, popviewcontroller

iOS 7 has introduced pan gesture to popViewController. It introductes problems with the sidebar that I am using so I want to prevent this new function of ios7. How can I cancel that behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use yourNavigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;